# Mule WSDL Connector

Tags: web-services, wsdl, mule, cxf, anypoint-studio

I use version 3.8 (3.8.3) . 
I basically want to host my wsdl in a different location other than http://{serviceurl}?wsdl like http://{serviceurl}/my-great-service.wsdl

At the following mule doc
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/wsdl-connectors

it says that `you can specify the _wsdlLocation_ property of the CXF endpoint as follows`

```
<endpoint address="wsdl-cxf:http://localhost:8080/book/services/BookService?method=getBooks">
   <properties>
      <property name="wsdlLocation" value="file:///c:/BookService.wsdl"/>
   </properties>
</endpoint>
```

But where to put this in the mule xml ?

To the root of the file `<mule> here  </mule>` or to `<flow> here </flow>` or to the `<cxf:proxy-service> here </cxf:proxy-service>`

The mule documentation is so limited and lock of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason why you are using the cxf connector instead of the web service consumer?

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/web-service-consumer

All the global configuration elements are specified after the `<mule>` tag and before the `<flow>` elements.

Example with web service consumer below:

```
<mule ......>
    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" service="ServiceService" 
    port="ServicePort" serviceAddress="addresUrl" 
    wsdlLocation="wsdl location" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>

    <flow>...</flow>
</mule>
```

If for any reason you want to use the cxf connector, is the same but using the cxf connector

Comment: I am proxying an existing soap service, that is because I chose to use cxf: proxy-service, I already have a web service consumer config for the service I am consuming. I wonder to change the url of my own service